# PHP - Glitchy mod (%) operator

Tags: php, operators, modulo, diffie-hellman

For some reason: the display looks like this:

```
3 to the power of x mod 17 is 19. This is called v.

Shared person a (v):
19
```

and in the script, it looks like this (this script is used to describe Diffie-Hellman key exchange algorithm.):

```
$p="17";
$g="3";
$px=gmp_nextprime(rand());
$x=gmp_strval($px);
$a=$g^$x%$p;
echo "$g to the power of x mod $p is $a. This is called v.<br>";
echo "<br>Shared person a (v):<br>";
echo "$a <br>";
```

Wondering if this is kind of a PHP glitch, because:

```
if{x mod y=z}, z<y
```

Now my questions: 
How to fix this? 
Had I done anything wrong? 
Is this a PHP glitch?

(The code needs a clean up, I know.)

Additional notes:
$x = 2047401017

Comment: Why aren't you using `gmp_powm()`? Especially with exponents that big.

Comment: Second problem I have: Numbers too large. PHP the language itself only support integers' size up to 2^31-1. I don't see 3^(2 billion) will do me good.

Comment: That's exactly why you should be using gmp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `^` is not the power operator *and* modulo precedes both of them; besides, GMP has a function for power-modulo already:

```
$p="17";
$g="3";
$px=gmp_nextprime(rand());

$a = gmp_powm($g, $px, $p);

echo "$g to the power of x mod $p is $a. This is called v.<br>";
echo "<br>Shared person a (v):<br>";
echo "$a <br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

`^` is not the exponent operator, it's the bitwise XOR operator. As of PHP 5.6, the exponent operator is `**`. So it should be either

```
$a = ($g ** $x) % $p;
```

or

```
$a = $g ** ($x % $p);
```

The exponent operator was added in PHP 5.6. Prior to this, you need to use the `pow()` function:

```
$a = pow($g, $x) % $p;
```

Comment: I like your answer, but I got this error:    PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '*'

Comment: The exponent operator was added in PHP 5.6. Sounds like you're running an older version.

Comment: "PHP Version 5.4.4-14+deb7u11" Thanks for tipping me off for being old-fashioned. That dragged me into updating Linux Headers. :)